# Decomposition of GL(2,p) into irreducible representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, projective-geometry

Let $G=GL(2,p)$ be the group of linear transformations. It acts on the set $X=F_p^2$.
Then $C^X$ is a linear representation of $G$. What is the decomposition of this representation into irreducible representations?

*Note*: Let $d_i$ denote the number of isomorphic irreducible representations. Then $\sum d_i^2$ is equal to the number of orbits of $G$ when $G$ acts on $X\times X$. The number of orbits of $G$ in $X\times X$ is equal to $p+1$.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the character table for $G$
can be found in various texts, for instance the third
edition of Lang's *Algebra*. The character of the permutation
representation on $X$ is easy to compute. Using the
orthogonality relations one gets the decomposition
of the permutation character into irreducibles. With
a little more work, one can get the decomposition on
the level of actual representations.

Comment: Acctually I want to know how $C^X$ decomposed and not just what irreducible represintations it contain, i.e. I want to know not only irreducible sub-repesintation in $C^X$ but also homomorphism from it to C^X.

Comment: To find the representations all you need is the characters. Each
character $\chi$ has a corresponding central idempotent $e_\chi$
in the group algebra. Hitting your representation with $e_\chi$
will give the sum of all irreps with character $\chi$ inside it.

Comment: What I've got so far: there are two obvious copies of the trivial representation: one coming from the fact that G fixes the origin, and the other coming from the fact that G fixes the sum over all points besides the origin.  There is also a subrepresentation spanned by sums over all the points contained in each line through the origin; the action of G on this subrepresentation factors through PSL(2, p), and since the action of PSL(2, p) on the projective line is doubly transitive this subrepresentation is irreducible.  

Comment: Another nice source for the computation of the character table is in Etingof's lectures on representation theory: http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/cltrunc.pdf

Comment: nice question !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  *This was written up concurrently with David's answer, but wasn't proofread and didn't get past the captcha stage due to technical problems.*

It is more common to consider the representation of $G=GL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ on $\mathbb{C}^Y$, where $Y=X\setminus 0$. This is a direct sum over all multiplicative characters $\chi$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$  of the induced representations of $G$ in the homogeneous functions of homogeneity degree $\chi:$

$$\mathbb{C}^Y=\bigoplus_{\chi\in \mathbb{F}_p^\ast}(\mathbb{C}^Y)_{\chi}, \quad (\mathbb{C}^X)_{\chi}=\{f:Y\to \mathbb{C}: f(\lambda a)=\chi(\lambda)f(a)\ \text{for all}\ \lambda\in \mathbb{F}_p \},$$

and $\mathbb{C}^X=\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}^Y,$ where the first summand corresponds to the functions supported at $0\in\mathbb{F}_p^2.$

Each induced representation has dimension $p+1.$ For the trivial character, the induced representation contains a trivial subrepresentation of $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ (constants), with irreducible $p$-dimensional quotient (Steinberg representation).  All other induced representations are irreducible and pairwise non-isomorphic (they all have different central characters). The situation is a bit more complicated for restrictions to $H=SL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ (denoted the same by abuse of notation): for any $\chi,\ (\mathbb{C}^Y)_{\chi}\simeq (\mathbb{C}^Y)_{\chi^{-1}}$ and if $p$ is odd and $\psi$ is a character of order $2$ then the representation $(\mathbb{C}^Y)_{\psi}$ is a direct sum of two non-isomorphic $(p+1)/2$-dimensional representations, all other representations remain irreducible and pairwise non-isomorphic. These facts can be verified *ad hoc* by the "sum of squares" calculation or, more systematically, by using the Mackey theory for finite groups. This accounts for close to the half of irreducible representations of $H$; to get the rest, one needs to induce from the non-split torus $\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p^2}^\ast/\mathbb{F}_{p}^\ast. $

Comment: Phew! Sudden power loss just a second after posting.

Comment: Thanks,
This answers my question about GL(2,p). Does the same works for GL(n,p)? Where can I read about Mackey theory for finite groups?

Comment: Yes, this works for $GL(n,p),$ but the representations you'll get will be more special (i.e. they will not look like "typical" representations of this group). I think Kirillov's "Elements of representation theory" describes Mackey theory, but this may be worth a separate MO question: I remember scratching my head trying to come up with a good reference. For this specific question, David's answer really walks you through the procedure without mentioning the big theorems that justify it in general. 

Answer (score 8):

There are $2$ copies of the trivial representation, and $p-1$ other representations. The two trivials are spanned by the characteristic function of $(0,0)$, and by the function which is $1$ on all the nonzero vectors and $0$ on $(0,0)$. The other representations are indexed by the characters of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$. Namely, for any character $\chi$, consider those functions $f:\mathbb{F}_p^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(g \cdot v)=\chi(g) f(v)$ for $g \in \mathbb{F}_p^*$. This is a subrepresentation. It is irreducible except when $\chi$ is trivial, in which case the two trivials split off as summands.

**How to do this computation**: Let $V$ be a representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $V:=\bigoplus W_{\chi} \otimes V_{\chi}$ be the decomposition into isotypic components, where $V_{\chi}$ are representatives for the isomorphism classes of $G$-irreps. Then 
$$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,V) = \bigoplus W_{\chi} \otimes W_{\chi}. \quad (*)$$
This formula is particularly useful when $V$ is a permutation representation $\mathbb{C}^X$, as then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V)$ is $\mathbb{C}^{X \times X}$ and the subalgebra of $G$-equivariant Homs is spanned by the $G$ orbits in $X \times X$. So the left hand side of $(*)$ has dimension equal to the number of $G$ orbits in $X \times X$. (In particular, we obtain the corollary mentioned by Qiaochu in a now-deleted answer: if the action of $G$ on $X \times X$ is doubly transitive, then $V$ is a trivial representation and one other irrep.)

In this case, there are $(p-1)+3+1$ orbits in $X \times X$. For every $g \in \mathbb{F}_p^*$, the set $\{ (v,w) : v=gw,\ v,w \neq 0 \}$ is an orbit. Also, we have three orbits by imposing that $v$, $w$ or both, be zero. Finally, there is the large orbit where $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent.

If we have already guessed the decomposition into irreducibles, as above, then we can confirm it by checking that the dimensions of both sides of $(*)$ match. In this case, that says $(p-1)+3+1=(p-1)+2^2$, which is true.

If we didn't already know the answer, we could deduce it from $(*)$. Let $R$ be the ring in $(*)$. We can describe $R$ as the vector space of $G$-invariant functions on $X \times X$, with the convolution product $(f*g)(u,w)=\sum_{v \in X} f(u,v) g(v,w)$. We must find the decomposition of $R$ into simple summands, and decompose $V$ as an $R$-module. The $R$-submodules of $V$ are the isotypic components for the $G$-action.

In this case, let $\Omega_g$ be the orbit  $\{ (v,w) : v=gw,\ v,w \neq 0 \}$. It is easy to check that the $\Omega_g$ span a subalgebra isomorphic to the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{F}_p^*]$. This, of course, is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{\chi} \mathbb{C}$, where the sum is over characters of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$. The idempotents for this decomposition project onto the corresponding $\chi$ representations above. The other semisimple summand of $R$ is a little harder to guess. Let $a_{00}$, $a_{10}$, $a_{01}$ and $a_{11}$ be the characteristic functions of the subsets of $X \times X$ where the two components are zero or nonzero according to whether the index is $0$ or $1$. Then the $a_{ij}$ span an algebra isomorphic to $\mathrm{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$, corresponding to the trivial summands.

You might enjoy reading the notes from the [2007 Quantum Gravity Seminar](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-fall2007/), which (despite its title) mostly focused on representation theory of finite groups. This is where I learned how to systematically use the ring $R$ to study permutation representations.

Comment: I am sorry I did not follow:
"The idempotents for this decomposition project onto the corresponding  representations above"

Can you, please, explain it?

I do understand how the ring R looks like, but I do not understand how to deduce from it irreducible represintations of $C^X$.